# Does Moshi support Iso8601 dates?

Tags: kotlin, moshi

I have the following Retrofit/Moshi setup to support Rfc3339 Dates:

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Config.getApiUrl())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(
                MoshiConverterFactory.create(
                    Moshi.Builder().add(Date::class.java, Rfc3339DateJsonAdapter())
                        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
                )
            )
            .build()
```

Sadly it throws this error, when it retrieves the `expires_at` below:
`Not an RFC 3339 date: 2021-03-20T20:24:00`

I realised then that the API returns ISO 8601 dates. (Fast-API in Python)

```
{
  "expires_at": "2021-03-21T17:08:00",
}
```

[Moshi Adapter](https://github.com/square/moshi/tree/master/adapters/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/adapters) doesn't seem to include an adapter for ISO 8601. Unless I'm not seeing the woods for the trees.

What am I missing please?

**UPDATE:**

Is it recommended using the `java.util.Date` for the date serialisation, when utilising the `Rfc3339DateJsonAdapter`?

```
import java.util.*

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class SignInJson(
    val product_id: String?,
    val expires_at: Date,
)
```

Comment: You're missing a `Z` at the end of that date string.

Comment: (and it should be straightforward to register a custom adapter for that format)

Comment: Thanks Jesse, yeah you're right. I added the Z to the API and now it works. Do you recommend using the `java.util.Date` for the Json serialisation? Please see updated question (at the bottom).

Comment: You can use whichever date abstraction you prefer. Moshi ships with Date because it's so widely available; it's straightforward to use javax.time and delegate to that one.